# How to get notified when a Visual Studio project is renamed (VSIX)?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, vsix, envdte

I'm building a Visual Studio extension and I need to get notification when a project is renamed.

Tried using `DTE2.Events2.SolutionEvents` and also tried `IVsSolutionEvents`.

Both of them work fine for C#, VB.NET, and F# projects, but not for C++ projects.

Is there another way to handle project rename events? Or something specific for C++ projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the [`IVsSolutionEvents4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents4.onafterrenameproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsSolutionEvents4_OnAfterRenameProject_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsHierarchy_) interface and its `OnAfterRenameProject` method?

For an [implementation](https://github.com/TwentyFourMinutes/DulcisX/blob/e3739087d4e40cf07dbe7d3b383878abdb45344e/src/DulcisX/DulcisX/Hierarchy/Events/SolutionEvents.cs#L231) you can take a look at my `DulcisX` framework.

Comment: I tried using IVsSolutionEvents4. for some reason it works only for C#, VB, and F#. But it won'r work for C++ projects. The event won't fire for C++ projects.

Comment: Tbf I have never actually tried it with C++ projects. The big problem here is that all "Project Types" have there own implementation. The only other thing I could think of would be the [`IVsRunningDocTableEvents3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdoctableevents3?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and there `OnAfterAttributeChange` methods. You will also need to call the `IVsRunningDocumentTable.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents` method with the class inheriting the before mentioned interface.

Comment: @omsharp if the `grfAttribs` parameter is equal to `4` and `pszMkDocumentOld != pszMkDocumentNew` something got renamed. The RDT should keep track of all sorts of editable files in a solution. An implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/TwentyFourMinutes/DulcisX/blob/master/src/DulcisX/DulcisX/Hierarchy/Events/OpenNodeEvents.cs#L124).

Comment: But that's for documents (files), not projects!

Comment: @omsharp It still triggers for Projects/Solutions at least for C# ones.